# sed appending filenames on newline

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to add filenames to many *txt files, which are tab-seperated (they will eventually be joined together using cat)
I am using bash, on Ubuntu 14.04.

So far my code is;

```
for f in *.txt
do
sed -i 's/$/'"       $f"'/' "$f"
done
```

This works fine except that the filenames are appended on the line below, and not to each row. I am using Ctrl-V Tab to insert my tab in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for f in *.txt
do
  sed -i -e '1,$s/$/'"       $f"'/' "$f"
done
```

if you are trying to do what I think you do: add a {tab} character and file name at the end of each line in all the .txt files in a directory

Comment: also instead of using `ctrl-v tab` combo to insert the tab character, you can use `\t` string to insert a tab in `sed`. So your sed line should look like this `sed -i -e '1,$s/$/'"\t$f"'/' $f`

Comment: Upvoted! But don' have enough reputation...